# jQuery: add attribute based on seperate label element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically mark a list of checkboxes as "checked" based on the checkbox label text.

Here is some example mark up:

```
    <li class="checkboxlist-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Categories_24" value="eb9d6610-914b-4e14-99d1-a22200cd5369" name="Categories.SelectedIds"  />
    <label for="Categories_24">Properties &amp; Moving</label>
</li>
```

So I'd like to mark the input element here as "checked" if the label text is "Properties & Moving"

Your help would be much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: have your tried anything? Share your code or do some research to your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), so you can be sure of the *exact* string:

```
$(".checkboxlist-item label").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Properties & Moving";
}).siblings(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vyGJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('label:contains(Properties & Moving)').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYF6R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each checkbox using `.each()` method. Then using `.next()`, you can find the label element next to that.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
if($(this).next().text()=="Properties & Moving")
{
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
}
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjmh/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('.checkboxlist-item label').text() == 'Properties Moving' )
 $('.checkboxlist-item input').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Find lable text via
if($("lable").text() == "Properties & Moving")
and then Add Checked code 
Like checked="checked"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
if($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').html()=="Properties &amp; Moving")
{
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
}
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BC2Q6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=='Properties &amp; Moving'){
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/3WLdN/)